# Call method in another class to set label text (don't use netbeans' default stuff)

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, label, edit

I'm using netbeans and want to edit the text in a label. I want to edit this label from another class in the main driver class. I have about 7 or 8 JDialog pages and let's say the label is on one of those pages.

When I try to call the method from one of those JDialogs so that I can edit it, it keeps asking for a java.awt.Frame. Where would I find that Frame name? Or, is there an easier way of editing labels from another class?

Netbeans makes labels private by default so I looked online and people have said making a setter method would be easiest.

QuickScreen is a .java file for instance...

```
public static void resetNumbers(){
    QuickScreen qs = new QuickScreen(some frame);
    qs.editLabel("Hello");
}
```

Please refer to my last comment on bmoran's solution.

Comment: I feel like you have a typo; should be qs.editLabel() not gs.editLabel()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the label you want to set to either default or protected level access, then you can set it from your dialog as long as both classes are in the same package (for default) or your dialog box extends the class that the label is in (protected).

```
    public class FrameClass extends JFrame {
        JLabel label1;// package access
        MyDialog dialog;

        //constructor *** Netbeans may have an init() method ***
        public FrameClass(){
        label1=new JLabel("Hello!");
        ...
        }

        ...
    }

public class MyDialog{
    public void changeLabel(){
        FrameClass.label1.setText("Good Bye!");
    }
}
```

Comment: They are both in the same package. How would I set the label to default if need be? And then how would I go about editing the label from the other class?

Comment: You will need to declare the label in the class as opposed to in a method like a constructor. You declare the label like Label label1=null;  By not specifying an access modifier, the object is given default access (sometimes referred to as package level access).

Comment: Sorry, I need this broken down more why I can't just call it like a method. The label is already created in the auto generated code by netbeans as private. It lets me create a method to modify it. I just want to call this method that I created inside of the main method but it keeps asking for a Frame. :(

Comment: Ok. Long story short... The way you were answering was absolutely correct and I thank you for you help bmoran. The solution was really to stop using netbeans as it was intended with automatic created class things and break things back down to their more rudimentary form (which is why java is so powerful). Make my own everything. By doing that I gain the access I want to everything. Also, for those thinking of using JDialog... only use it for quick messages. JForm is much better and easier to use. Thanks for everyone's concern on this matter. :)

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for a few years now and have never had a problem. I use the Window Builder Pro plugin to create swing applications very easily with drag-and-drop. [Window Builder Pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/download-wbpro.html)

Comment: Not going to lie... Window Builder Pro is amazing. The only thing I don't like (which there may be a work around) is that eclipse doesn't have the menu drop down list when you have a variable or method of another object.